# Installing porch light

Tags: electrical, wiring

An outdoor porch light has SPT Wire and the wire to which it is attached is an NM WIRE.  How do I know which wire goes to white & which goes with black or does it not matter.

Answer (score 4):

One of the SPT conductors will have ribs running along it's length, that is the neutral and will connect to the white.